# What's a robust way of obtaining updated instances in an NHibernate object graph after a Session.Merge?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

In my domain I deal entirely in disconnected entities from the perspective of NHibernate (version 3.1). Accordingly, when mapping from my primary domain to my rdbms domain, I call `Session.Merge` on the rdbms entities because the graph contains a mixture of persistent and transient instances - some exist already, and some are new and need adding to the database.

Say I have the following model (pseudo)

```
class Post
{
  ISet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

class Comment
{
  Post Post { get; set; }
  string UnimportantString { get; set; }
}
```

I have an object instance for the `Post` obtained from the `Session`, and a new (transient) `Comment` instance `myComment`, created as a result of mapping from my domain model.
I add this to that existing `Post`:

```
myComment.Post = myPost;
myPost.Comments.Add(myComment);
myPost = Session.Merge(myPost);
```

Assume please that this is wrapped in units of work.
By calling `Session.Merge` on `myPost`, by design NHibernate does not modify the existing instances in the supplied graph, but returns different instances that are either created or were already in the 1st-level cache. So although the returned `myPost` now contains a persistent instance of the comment, the original `myComment` instance to which my code has a reference has not been modified.

I wish to map the modified entities back to my primary domain, but I'm lacking a robust way to select the modified `Comment` from the merged `myPost.Comments`. I'm assuming that `myPost.Comments.Last()` is not guaranteed to be the one I just added.

I wish to robustly correlate which entry in the freshly-merged `myPost.Comments` set correlates to my original `myComment` instance, for example so that I may obtain the ID as a result of the transaction completing. I can't do it by ID because my original myComment was a new object. I can't call SaveOrUpdate on myComment because this is a simplified example of a much more complex graph - there are other properties and a deeper graph and I want to be able to reliably correlate NHibernate's new instances with the original instances I supplied to it.

What's the best way of grabbing the updated `Comment` after a `Session.Merge(myPost)` so that I can map it back to my primary domain model?

***p.s.** Unfortunately just changing the call to `myComment = Session.Merge(myComment)` isn't sufficient as I have other objects too that I want to reference following a single call to `Merge`, not just this one `Comment` in my simplified example*

***p.p.s.** This contrived example hides the fact, but I use Session.Merge because in the process of mapping from my primary domain to my rdbms domain I end up with a graph that may contain persistent, transient and/or dirty entities*

Comment: `UnimportantString` - must be the YouTube comment system.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to this and I've implemented it by using the [entity version](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-5-basic-o-r-mapping#5%282E%291%282E%297%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29version_%2828%29optional%2829%29) feature of NHibernate. Using this, I can supply the ID of the entity ahead of time and then reliably match the updated entities.